# Innovation: Single sign on integrated with web filter?

Tags: user-management, g-suite, single-sign-on, webfilter

This one is a doozy, so be forewarned! Also please let me know if this isn't on the correct site.

What I would like to implement in the form of a server appliance is a single sign on solution that would integrate with "cloud" apps such as salesforce.com or google apps. But I would also like this initial login to determine what websites the user can access. I really don't know the terminoligy that is involved with all of these things, so I will try to paint a picture step by step:

1. User sits down at computer, opens website and is directed to a SSO login page (without logging in the user can't access any other sites, similar to a coffee shop).
2. After logging in, the user is connected to a SSO portal with links to launch the various web applications. User can now access allowed websites.
3. User logs out and now back at step one.

What I am trying to do is remove the network authentication from the computer and place it into the web browser, if that makes sense? The thought is less reliance on the operating system and local infrastructure, and more emphases on integrating the "cloud" services. I would like to either find similar software, or possibly start putting a group together towards a open source type project that could be built on linux?

I know this is off the wall, but if anyone could at least possibly name the technology or protocol that would be used in each step, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks, 
-Tim

Comment: Setup a thin-client, or system that opens a browser.  Buy something like [Stoneware Webnetwork](http://www.stone-ware.com/site/index.html), and setup a protal.

Answer (score 2):

The [Barracuda Web Filter](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/web-filter-overview.php) product line allows [Active Directory (or LDAP) authentication](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/downloads/Other/Barracuda_Web_Filter_Managing_Users_Groups.pdf) and can establish web access rules based on user/group memberships. This allows very granular rules. If the user is logged onto the Active Directory domain, the access can be transparent.

The portal you speak of can be an internal site or something you create. However, if you have specific links or sites that you will allow, just restrict the users/groups to those destinations.

Keep in mind that you can also create local users/groups on the appliance to govern access. Or you could have your directory server in the "cloud"...